# Zoom in on a photo in Quick Look in macOS Mojave Beta

Tags: shortcut, quicklook, mojave, beta

One invaluable Quick Look feature which I used to use pre-Mojave was pressing the "alt/option" button when using Quick Look to view a photo, which zoom in on the photo to its actual size. However, it seems like on Mojave this changes the orientation of the rotate button on the Quick Look toolbar, a feature I do not expect to use.

Is there an easy shortcut in Quick Look on Mojave, like the alt/option shortcut which existed pre-Mojave, which I can use to get back the old behavior, or has this useful feature been completely removed?