# Zoom in on photo in Quick Look on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, quicklook

In versions of macOS before macOS Mojave (10.14), one could press the <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd> key when viewing an image in Quick Look to zoom in to the "actual size" of the photo.

When the macOS Mojave beta came out, it seemed as though that feature was removed. I asked a question about it [on here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328431/zoom-in-on-a-photo-in-quick-look-in-macos-mojave), and it turned out that the shortcut key was changed to <kbd>Control</kbd>.

In the last few beta versions of macOS Mojave as well as the public release, unfortunately, this does not seem to be working anymore. I tried all combinations of modifier keys that I could think up of, but nothing seems to work.

Is there any other new shortcut for zooming an image in Quick Look on macOS Mojave?

Comment: I've merged the questions to avoid having two questions basically asking the same thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is there any other new shortcut for zooming an image to actual size in Quick Look on the latest version of macOS Mojave?

In the public release of macOS Mojave 10.14, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> keyboard sequence appears to achieve the desired function.

To zoom back out again use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>.

You can use Command+ and Command- to Zoom in and Zoom Out, like you can do at Preview app.

Comment: And it's Command + 9 to zoom back out again! Thanks!

Comment: CMD+0 and CMD+9 really works. But it's awful usage. It is not comfortable to push so many keys for just simple and IMPORTANT work — quick zoom in (actual size) and quick zoom out. ALT was perfect for that way, but ALT is gone:(

Comment: @AndreyYashin As per my understanding, the change has been made to bring it in line with the Preview.app shortcuts. You may wish to file a radar.

Comment: This is a huge regression for me as well. AND it doesn't work in fullscreen ><

Comment: If this worked before, it appears to no longer work.  The view will often open fit-to-window but for subsequent images it does not.  CMD-0 and CMD-9 does nothing.  I think this functionality was badly broken by the Mojave release.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this, and copied it to openradar:
https://openradar.appspot.com/48848294

Comment: ...annnd one day later, Apple replied to my bug report with a smackdown: "Thank you for your feedback, it is noted. Engineering has determined that there are currently no plans to address this issue. Command + 0 and Command + 9 are the standard used by QuickLook and Preview on the system. We are now closing this bug report."

Comment: Do you guys know, if there's any way to edit some plist or other files containing settings for these buttons? 
It's so braindead that they've removed a one button extremely easy and useful feature, and replaced it with complicated key combination.

Comment: In Monterey neither control, alt or CMD + 9 or 0 work...seems they've either changed it again or removed the function completely. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Command + 0 and Command + 9 work for me in Catalina

Answer (score 3):

In the beta, it was <kbd>Control</kbd> to actual size, <kbd>Option</kbd> to come back to fit in

Comment: Was there an option to enable this? This does not work on a fresh install of Mojave final.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Trackpad (or similar), you can use the "parting two-fingers" gesture to zoom in on a QuickLook preview.